# working with graphic interface on ssh linux

Tags: linux, ssh, xterm

We have a project involving Linux programming. Unfortunately, we have only an ssh interface, and not a convenient graphic one. What can we do? We heard that xterm can solve our problems, but we couldn't run it properly (We get: cant open DISPLAY, depite the fact that we tried DISPLAY=:0.0 and export DISPLAY=:0.0),and despite the fact that we have roots permissions.

We found some issues on the linux forums, for example http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/xterm-error-display-not-set-583271/, but it didn't help...

How we can convert to a grqphic interface?

Answer (score 1):

type

> ssh -X username@remote_machine

-X     Enables X11 forwarding.  This can also be specified on a per-host basis in a configuration file.

but to make this work make sure that "X11Forwarding" directive in /etc/ssh/sshd_config in the remote server is set to "yes"

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [X11 forwarding](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/XDMCP-HOWTO/ssh.html).

You might look at [Xming](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/) & [X2go](http://www.x2go.org/index.php?id=1&L=5).

Comment: How does on use X11 forwarding?